# Specific view for specific category in Magento 2

Tags: category, magento-2.2.5

How to create specific **view(list/grid)** for specific **category**.

In Magento the default will be **applied to all the categories**, but need specific **view for one category**.

Answer (score 0):

you need to override **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar** block for this customization.

> ../vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

**Declare Registry Object  :**

```
protected $registry;

public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->registry = $registry;
        ...
    }
```

**Replace getCurrentMode() function**

```
public function getCurrentMode()
    {
        $mode = $this->_getData('_current_grid_mode');
        if ($mode) {
            return $mode;
        }
        $defaultMode = $this->_productListHelper->getDefaultViewMode($this->getModes());
        $mode = $this->_toolbarModel->getMode();
        if (!$mode || !isset($this->_availableMode[$mode])) {
            $mode = $defaultMode;
        }

        $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', $mode);
        return $mode;
    }
```

**with**

```
public function getCurrentMode()
{
    $current_category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
    $parent_category = $current_category->getParentCategory();
    if($current_category->getName() == 'Energy'){ // You Category name
        $mode = 'list'; // View Mode (grid/list)
        return $mode;
    }

    $mode = $this->_getData('_current_grid_mode');
    if ($mode) {
        return $mode;
    }
    $defaultMode = $this->_productListHelper->getDefaultViewMode($this->getModes());
    $mode = $this->_toolbarModel->getMode();
    if (!$mode || !isset($this->_availableMode[$mode])) {
        $mode = $defaultMode;
    }

    $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', $mode);
    return $mode;
}
```

Don't forgot to clean caching, flushing , upgrading before testing..